# Doxygen and Markdown auto numbering lists

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I am looking for auto numbering of a list, with it being acceptable by the standard Markdown (used by VS - code) and Doxygen.

`-#` is not acceptable by the standard Markdown.

Giving to all the lines `1.` is not recognized by Doxygen.

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: Is there really something like *standard markdown*? This precise markup language comes in [many flavors](https://github.com/commonmark/CommonMark/wiki/Markdown-Flavors).

Answer (score 3):

According to [Doxygen's manual](http://doxygen.nl/manual/lists.html), you should use `-#` or `<ol>` for auto-numbering lists.

Moreover, there is not really a standard in Markdown (there are [experiments](http://commonmark.org) to make one, but there is no clear industry standard).

> By putting a number of column-aligned minus (-) signs at the start of a line, a bullet list will automatically be generated. Instead of the minus sign also plus (+) or asterisk (*) can be used.
>
> **Numbered lists can also be generated by using a minus followed by a hash or by using a number followed by a dot.**
>
> If you like you can also use **HTML commands** inside the documentation blocks.